# Do I get an EU Blue Card from Germany if my degree is not listed in ANABIN and my university is listed H+

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, blue-card, education

I've just got a visa of type D for Germany to work for a big company in Berlin. The relocation company that assisting me told me that

> Kindly note that is has not been issued on the legal basis of a blue card. However, after your arrival in Germany and the registration at the local town hall, we will contact the immigration office if they are willing to change the legal basis to a blue card. However the current visa and legal basis allows you to reside and work in Germany without any restrictions.

Because the Embassy is saying that my degree is not recognized.

My university is ranked #1 in Jordan and it is listed in the ANABIN website as `H+` but the degree which is `Computer Science` (4 years Bachelor degree) is not listed under it and listed just under other universities that are much less popular than it.

Does it mean that I am not going to get a Blue Card ?
Is there anything to do ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a definitive answer, but I can provide an anecdotal data point.

My Canadian university is listed in Anabin with `H+` as well, and my specific degree is **not** listed in their list (still).

I proactively sent a certified copy of my degree to the KMK for recognition, and when I applied for a Blue Card in 2016, the Ausländeramt in NRW wanted the recognition from the KMK for my degree. I provided it and was granted a Blue Card without any other issues.

Note: the fee from KMK for degree recognition cost me 300€ and took just over 3 months

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit strange that a degree of a top university is not listed on Anabin. Make sure you checked all variations "Bachelor of Science", "Engineering", "BSc in Computer Eng" etc.

If it is really not there, you need to get it assessed. You can use the following page outlining foreign degree recognition and evaluation for Berlin:

https://www.berlin.de/sen/wissenschaft/studium/abschluesse-und-titelfuehrung/