# My Masters Degree (2 years) and University exist in Anabin database, but only University of my Bachelors Degree (4 years) exist but not the degree

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have 4 years of Bachelors and 2 years of Masters.
University and Degree title of my Masters Degree exist in Anabin.

Only University is there in Anabin with H+ rating of my bachelor's degree but not the degree itself.
For my Bluecard application, can I attach only my Masters degree extract from Anabin or do I have to get ZAB Certificate of Comparability?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I get an EU Blue Card from Germany if my degree is not listed in ANABIN and my university is listed H+](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15196/do-i-get-an-eu-blue-card-from-germany-if-my-degree-is-not-listed-in-anabin-and-m)

Comment: No. because I was thinking because my Master's degree exist in Anabin, maybe I can skip the ZAB!

Comment: Sorry I am not going to answer this question but I am facing a similar problem in which my both Masters and bachelors institutions and degree types are equivalent. However My master degree specifically is not equivalent. I mean masters is listed and Entspricht but not Masters of Engineering in Electronic s and communication. Does the visa office asks for specific degrees also ?